# iPhone security architecture references

Tags: iphone, security

recently i've googled about iphone os security architecture over the net but i have yet to find any comprehensive documentation or whitepaper on iphone os security architecture.

Is there anyone who know some sources and is able point me to some of the references?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you are asking. Are you asking what security services iOS provides. In that case look at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Architecture/Architecture.html

Or are you looking at how the iPhone secures itself from tampering etc... Good luck with that because they don't want you to know.

Comment: yes, actually i was looking for technical explaination of the technologies used in iPhone, for example their iOS ASLR. But after searching several days, i believe the sources for all these are very very limited. Thanks for your reply!